# Probablity of network flow

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Three vertices: X, Y, Z
Three edges: edge a (Vertex X to Y), edge b (Vertex Y to Z), edge c (Vertex Y to Z [yes another edge connecting it]).

I want to know the probability of X to Z (as in flow from X to Z) if
edge a has probability of .9
edge b has probability of .8
P(edge a intersects edge b) = .75
edge c has probability of .5
a and b is independent of edge c

*note you can reach vertex z from X with edge a and b OR edge a and c.

So, I was thinking P(a U b) = P(a) + P(b) - P( a intersects b);
P(a Union b) or P(a)*P(c) which is adding those two 1.3 or 130% which doesnt make sense.

Anyone know how to approach this problem?

or maybe multiplying them instead of adding them?
them = P(a U b) and P(a U c) = .95*.45 = .4275 which seems a bit low to gettin to Z from X

Comment: What do you mean by "P(edge a intersects edge b) = .75" -- do you mean probability that flow occurs on these is dependent (otherwise should be $.9 \cdot .8 = .72$?

Comment: yes correct. if it was independent it would be .72. independent is for a to c

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/236635.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let E be flow from X to Z.

For E,as you said, you need A and at least one of B or C so

$P(E) = P (A\cap(B \cup C))= $

by De Moivre rule
$=P ((A\cap B )\cup (A\cap C))= P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap C) -P((A\cap B) \cap (A \cap C))= $

because of independence of C from all other events
$=P(A \cap B) + P(A)P(C) -P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A \cap B) + P(A)P(C) -P(A\cap B)P(C)=$

inputing values
$.75 + .9*.5-.75*.5=.825$

Which is the very same thing as in here [Calculating the probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236635/calculating-the-probability)

Comment: great! thank you! this makes sense now